# Square root in $\mathbb F_{2^n}$

Tags: finite-fields, primitive-roots

Let $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ be a finite field with $2^n$ elements.

I am just wondering if it is true that for all $n\in \mathbb N$ all elements of $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ have square roots, i.e for all $a\in \mathbb F_{2^n}$ there is an element $b\in \mathbb F_{2^n}$, with $a=b^2$?

It may be very easy but I can not see now how to see it.

Comment: The nonzero elements of the field form a cyclic group of odd order. From this, it's immediate that every element has a square root.

Comment: Sorry, I see that $\mathbb F_{2^n}^*$ is cyclic how do we infer the conclusion from this?

Comment: The map that takes $x$ to $x^2$ is a group isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in \Bbb F_{2^n}$ be two elements with $x^2=y^2\implies (x-y)(x+y)=0$, since a field is an integral domain we have either $x=y$ or $x=-y=y$ as $\text{char}(\Bbb F_{2^n})=2$. Hence, $x\not=y\iff x^2\not=y^2$, so that $\big\{x^2|x\in \Bbb F_{2^n}\big\}=\Bbb F_{2^n}$. So every element is a square root.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see your point.

Comment: Hm, $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb F_{2^n})=2$ means that $2x=0$. But I do not see $\{x^2\mid x\in \mathbb F_{2^n}\}=\mathbb F_{2^n}$ :(

Comment: $2x=0\implies x=-x$. So, $x\not =y\iff x^2\not =y^2$. Note, that we are working in a finite set

Comment: Oh, with Gerry Meyerson comment now I see. Thanks you both.

Answer (score 0):

Do u know that for every $a\in \mathbb F_{2^n}$
$a^{2^n}-a=0$.

Comment: Is your answer better than accepted one?

Comment: Solution can't be sorted.